# How to delete the selected text from CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am developing an application where I am using CKEditor. I have provided a button called clear. 
Whenever user selects some part of text and clicks on clear button only the selected text should get deleted.

I used the below code in my application but whenever user clicks on clear button not only selected text but whole content gets deleted.

```
 function clear_onclick() {
        CKEDITOR.instances.message.setData('');
 }
```

How can I clear the selected text from CKEditor on click of clear button in ASP.Net MVC2?

Answer (score 11):

This will do the job:

```
var range = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getSelection().getRanges()[ 0 ];
range.deleteContents();
range.select(); // Select emptied range to place the caret in its place.
```

Comment: how can i get the current cursor position in CKEDITOR?

Comment: It's in the `range` variable created in first line in my answer. You need to learn how to use DOM ranges.

Comment: I can only send you http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range and http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html
To do anything with ranges you need to understand them first.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances["textAreaId"].getSelection().getSelectedText().setData('');
```

Comment: its not working for me ...Am getting error as 
CKEDITOR.instances.message.getSelection(...).getSelectedText(...).setData is not a function

Comment: <textarea class="ckeditor" id="message" name="message"></textarea> message is the id of textarea